# PHP check if a variable is LIKE an item in an array using in_array

Tags: php

I am creating this array with the below code:

```
$ignored = array();
foreach(explode("\n", $_POST["ignored"]) as $ignored2) {
    $ignored[] = $ignored2;
}
```

and i want to check if any item inside the array is LIKE a variable. I have this so far:

```
if(in_array($data[6], $ignored)) {
```

but I'm not sure what to do with the LIKE

Comment: Define what exactly *like* means. Case-insensitive?

Comment: like an SQL query (SELECT * from table where col1 LIKE %...%)

Comment: *A bit like* or *exactly like* LIKE?

Comment: So does that include handling wild cards, *ahem*, `LIKE '%term%'`? You need to explain what the rules are you're looking for.

Comment: In your foreach loop, add a strpos function to check is the variable is "like" $ignored2  :   strpos($ignored2, $myVariable) !== false

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` doesn't provide this type of comparison. You can make your own function as follows:

```
<?php
function similar_in_array( $sNeedle , $aHaystack )
{

    foreach ($aHaystack as $sKey)
    {
        if( stripos( strtolower($sKey) , strtolower($sNeedle) ) !== false )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }    
    return false;
}
?>
```

You can use this function as:

```
if(similar_in_array($data[6], $ignored)) {
    echo "Found";   // ^-search    ^--array of items
}else{              
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Function references:

1. [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)
2. [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)
3. [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well, like is actually from SQL world.
You can use something like this:

```
  $ignored = array();
  foreach(explode("\n", $_POST["ignored"]) as $ignored2) {
      $ignored[] = $ignored2;
      if ( preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $ignored2) ) {
         //do what you want...
      }
  }
```

UPDATE: Well, I found this answer, may be it's what you need:

[Php Search_Array using Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592120/php-search-array-using-wildcard)

Comment: i want to run the if statement outside the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it that can be [customized fairly easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026135/451969), using a [`lambda` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php):

```
$words = array('one','two','three','four');
$otherwords = array('three','four','five','six');

while ($word = array_shift($otherwords)) {
    print_r(array_filter($words, like_word($word)));
}

function like_word($word) {
    return create_function(
        '$a', 
        'return strtolower($a) == strtolower(' . $word . ');'
    );
}
```

http://codepad.org/yAyvPTIq

To add different checks, simply add more conditions to the `return`. To do it in a single function call:

```
while ($word = array_shift($otherwords)) {
    print_r(find_like_word($word, $words));
}

function find_like_word($word, $words) {
    return array_filter($words, like_word($word));
}

function like_word($word) {
    return create_function(
        '$a', 
        'return strtolower($a) == strtolower(' . $word . ');'
    );
}
```